# Java how a class A can have multiple potential extends

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns

Hello i have a problematic about inheritance.

Let's have this three :

```
           A
         /   \
        /     \
       B       C
       \       /
        \     /
           ?
           |
           D


    abstract class A {
        public abstract void print();
        public abstract int getInt();
    }

    abstract class B extends A {
        @Override
        public int getInt() {
          return 5;
        }
    }

    abstract class C extends A {
        @Override
        public int getInt() {
           return 1;
        }
    }


    class D extends B || C {
        @Override
        public void print() {
         console.log(this.getInt());
       }
    }
```

I want add a class D who can herit from B or C.

And when i create a new D(), i could choose the parent. I don't want use multiple inheritance (well java can't do it too), i would like to use a way to add specific comportment on a class by changing the implementation of his parent.

In fact **D** should herit from **A** but with the special implementation of **B or C** that i could choose at runtime. We can consider that B and C doesn't allow to implement other method than A one.

is that possible ?

Comment: "Implementation chosen at runtime" sounds like the Strategy Pattern to me.

Comment: Or more generally, "[composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)".

Comment: Why don't you just use the Strategy or Template Method patterns along with the Factory pattern?

Comment: Agree with markspace. The factory method pattern may be an option to, but only if B and C were concrete classes. Strategy sounds like a sensible solution.

Comment: @luk2302 i didn't success to implement your exemple

Comment: Straegy pattern looks like a trick by storing B or C as A in my D class. That's a way i envisaged but it force me to duplicate code of A in D. no other way ? thanks for your replies

Answer (score 0):

C++ has multiple inheritance, and when Java was designed, instead of multiple inheritance *interfaces* were introduced, to provide a code alternative, and prevent ambiguity and other concerns with multiple inheritance.

One could use *delegation* instead, then the *strategy* of resolving the correct multiple calls is with the class.

```
class D extends A {
    B b;
    C c;

    @Override
    public int getInt() {
      return b.getInt() + c.getInt();
    }
    ...
}

class D extends A {
    A delegatee;

    public final void iAmReally(A a) {
        delegatee = a;
    }

    @Override
    public int getInt() {
      return delegatee.getInt();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: According to previous replies, it looks like the only way. But the strategy pattern force me to duplicate code of A, so i think i will try to find another trick. So, actually Java doesn't allow in any way to change the parent of a class at runtime ?

Comment: There are Proxy classes against interfaces, but primarily there is just single inheritance